# Visual C++ 10 - keeps attempting to build project instead of file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

So after having created a new project, saving it to my desktop, then creating a new cpp file within that project, I try to debug/run the file and immediately receive an error that says it can't find the specified project (not even the cpp file).

Can someone give me a really quick explanation of how I can open multiple cpp files under different names and just build/run them without any problems?  I've been trying to figure this out for the past hour and have only gotten increasingly frustrated with the system.  I WILL LOVE YOU FOREVER.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All files must be a part of a project. Quite like all men 'must have a father'. So you need to attach you cpp file to an empty project. you may use the 'new project' wizard to create a new **empty** project appropriate for your target and attach 'existing' file - you cpp file to this project. You should be able to build then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the file to your project it's not enough if it's in the same directory. And you need to open the project, not the .cpp file.

You can't just run single .cpp files, 'cause that would be a usable feature for a change (Not like you can do with any other enviroment, but still).

If you're hating VS, I say you're on the right track. Get MinGW and you can build a simple c++ file with gcc in a flash, from the command line (real programmers build from command line)

```
g++.exe some-file.cpp -o some-file.exe
some-file.exe
```

(you first need to add the bin directory in mingw to your path, of course)

Bottom line, you should not start using VS if you can still live without it, It's not the worse out there but still pretty down. And it's slow, and have very annoying "features".
You can't need more than notepad++ to write c++ code.